# Mercurial: Branching for releases?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, release

Previous history: The last couple of years I used SVN. Releasing a new version of a software project included following steps:

1. creating a branch for the new release: /repo/branches/0.1
2. getting the code into a release-worthy state there
3. creating a tag for a release candidate: /repo/tags/0.1-RC1
4. creating branch for RC1 to fix bugs: /repo/branches/0.1-RC1
5. creating tag for a new release candidate: /repo/tags/0.1-RC2
6. {...}
7. creating a tag for v0.1 from the last RC: /repo/tags/0.1
8. merging 0.1 into trunk

As far as I got Mercurial sees branches and tags slightly different than SVN and this finally leads to my question:

Do I create branches (and tags) for releases? And if not: What else wants Mercurial me doing to archive something similar to the described development pattern/cycle?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily keep using this method. I'm not sure what you'd need a separate RC1 branch for, but I guess there are good reasons.

There is a bit of an annoyance in the way tags are stored in Mercurial, which is a versioned file listing them one by one. As a result tag creation constitutes a changeset. You should strive to keep all such tag-creating changesets on one branch, or you will get merge conflicts (which are easily resolved, but annoying nonetheless).

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. Regarding branch for RC1: This was just the way we did it in my first project and being a junior I was not questioning it. Now having my own project I just kept doing it anyways.

The last part of your answer do not understand completely. Could you please elaborate it a bit further?

Comment: You'll have to experience it yourself :). Mercurial stores tags in a fairly innocent file inside the managed code tree (.hgtags). For this reason, said file can potentially diverge between branches, leading to almost certain merge conflicts when merging back. If this does not bother you, then ignore the issue. But since it does not matter in which branch the tags are kept – tag "A" can be created in branch B0, but refer to a changeset in branch B1 –, it would be nice to create all tags on the same branch. You can even use a branch dedicated to just track tag information, which you never merge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use old workflow, but:

- Branch per release *really* needed (in any SCM) only if you have to maintain some amount (>1) of releases in production at the same time, gor single maintained release branches-tree not needed
- I see a lot of (rather complex) projects, which use two-branches method ("Stable" with mergesets only and tags + "Devel" for every-day development (short-term branch-per-task are also possible, but it's more question of tastes and habits, than "a must")